# Name of a custom Goode homolosine projection

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, homolosine

What is the specific name of this homolosine projection? I see that America is closer to Europe/Africa than in the typical homolosine. [image: projection source]

Comment: I'm not every customised projection has a name - this might have been created specially for this one map. Some image searching shows homolosine maps with bits repeated (eg east Greenland and Iceland) are rare, and those where the chunks are not just interrupted but cut out and the lobes slid closer together are even rarer - can't find any!

Comment: See the gap in the Atlantic? That pretty much guarantees that the map maker has omitted part of the Atlantic in order to fit the map onto the page.

Answer (score 2):

That cartogram is just a patch of several segments obtained from the Homolosine projection. The author assortedly removed ocean segments to focus on land masses. An interesting choice, the reader looses the notion of the dimension of the oceans, but keeps well informed of the shapes and areas of land masses and countries.